# Cmake cant find the required Packages for me

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

So [My Workspace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlEyC.png) After Trying a while i cant Get Cmake To find the required packages even after i did everything as shown in vcpkg

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TEst VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "N:/Vc-PKG/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TEst PRIVATE glfw)
add_executable(TEst main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

and my Vcpkg install directory is `N:\Vc-PKG\vcpkg`
i also added these lines in vscode

```
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "N:/Vc-PKG/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include",
        "N:/Vc-PKG/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include",
    ],
    "c-cpp-flylint.cppcheck.includePaths": [
        "N:\\Vc-PKG\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\include",
        "N:\\Vc-PKG\\vcpkg\\installed\\x86-windows\\include",
    ],
    "cmake.generator": "MinGW Makefiles",
```

The output i get For the following is

```
[main] Configuring folder: Junks 
[proc] Executing command: N:\MSYS64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=N:\MSYS64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=N:\MSYS64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe "-Hl:/Programming Projects/Vs Code/Junks" "-Bl:/Programming Projects/Vs Code/Junks/build" -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     glfw3Config.cmake
[cmake]     glfw3-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "L:/Programming Projects/Vs Code/Junks/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cmake]
```

Please any help would be much apricated, sry if i made a mistake this is the 1st time i am posting a question.

Comment: Did you already `vcpkg integrate install`?

Comment: Yes i already did vcpkg intergrate install , it worked on my home pc fine with Visual Studio buy on my laptop in Vscode i coudnt make it to get working

Comment: Did ypu set vcpkg_DIR somewhere(in ```env``` or in **cmakelists.txt**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` after the call to `project()`. That's the command responsible for loading the toolchain file in the first place. Move it before the call to `project()` or better yet: set it at the command line or in a preset.

Also, unless you're actually using CMake 3.0.0, you shouldn't set it as a minimum. CMake is not forwards compatible, so without actually testing it on the minimum version, you have no way of knowing whether it will work that far back.

Comment: @M.F.R.Siam - Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it (check mark) and/or upvoting it (up arrow).